# Clear form but keep values for radios/checkboxes/hidden

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to clear a form. I am trying to remove the values for text boxes then unselect radios/checkboxes but keep the values of them and hidden inputs.

I have this so far but it removes the values for my radios/checkboxes and hidden inputs.

```
$(':input','#form1')
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .val('')
 .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling `val('')`, you already removing the content of your element's, try this:

```
$(':input','#form1')
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');
```

Comment: small improvement: $(":input:not(:button, :submit, :reset, :hidden)", "#form1").removeAttr("checked").removeAttr("selected");